# How to get List of records using soql then acess that list from vf page JS

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have a apex controller which have list of Custom object Student record List

```
public with sharing class get studentlist{
  public List<Student__c> students {get; set;}

 public studentlist(){
   List<Student__c> getStudents = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Student__c];
   List<Student__c> students;
   for(Student__c stu : getStudents ){
            students .add(stu);
   }
 }
}



<apex:page controller="studentlist">
  <script>
   var requests = []; 
</script>

    <apex:repeat value="{!students }" var="request"> 
        <script> 
            requests.push('{!request}'); 
        </script> 
    </apex:repeat> 
<script>

        window.onload = alertRequest;    

        function alertRequest(){
            console.log('requests', {!students});
         alert(requests[0]);

        }

    </script> 

</apex:page>
```

what mistake I am doing getting result as undefined.

or give me a way that I can access the List from apex to js in visualforce

Answer (score 0):

You're populating 2 local variables in the constructor instead of the class-level one. You redeclared a variable with same name,it's called "[shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm)".

This should fix your constructor:

```apex
public List<Student__c> students {get; set;}

public studentlist(){
    students = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Student__c];
}
```

As for passing data from apex to js - have you heard about "remoting"? Decent comparison of methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73085610/313628 (shameless plug)